# Preloading ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am creating a little application that has one feature to show list of people in popup when user click on button. That list, that is in popup, can be pretty big, it can have as many as 3k entries. I am using virtualization, and I don't have problem with performance when list is drawn. But, when user open application for the first time and click on button for popup with list of people, it can take 2-5 seconds before popup is shown. After, that if user try to open popup again popup will be open without delay.

So my question is could I say to ListView to prepare items while it is not shown. Because there is very big chance that user will use application for quiet some time before it will need this popup.

Can I optimize this in some other way? Is there some collection that is better for this purpose in WPF?

Also people collection will be populated when page is loaded, and popup is at beginning closed.

Here it is code that I have:

```
public class AddressBookViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   ...
   private ObservableCollection<PeopleModel> people;
   ...
   public ObservableCollection<PeopleModel> People
   {
      get { return people; }
   }
}

public class PeopleModel
{
   public PeopleModel(string address, string name)
   {
      Address = address;
      Name = name;
   }

   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
}

<Button x:Name="btnChoosePerson"
   Command="{Binding TogglePeopleAddressPopupCommand}"
   Content="..." />
<Popup MaxHeight="520"
   IsOpen="{Binding ShowPeopleAddressPopup}"
   Placement="Bottom"
   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnChoosePerson}"
   StaysOpen="False">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="5" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ListView
     Grid.Row="2"
     Width="500"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
     SelectionMode="Single"
     VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
     VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="10"
     VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Item">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Text="{Binding Address}" />
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Text="{Binding Name}"/>
       </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Grid>
</Popup>
```

Comment: How are you so sure that your bottleneck is in the UI and not elsewhere, such as network connections, assembly loading, db access, etc, etc, etc??

Comment: Well, person data is loaded from file when application is loaded, before any UI is shown. Application should be as simple as possible so I don't use database. When I initially load data from file, data stay in memory. Application isn't using any data from internet. So when I start application and it isn't doing anything useful, just showing data, I still have this problem. But as I said only first time when user want to open popup.

Comment: I copied you code into a new project and ran the app; the popup showed instantly.  So I would suggest the issue is not in the xaml.  How and when are you populating People collection?

Comment: You are absolutely right. When I create application with popup and button it work like charm. So I suppose that I don't have problem with xaml and wpf. Good point, thank you guys.